# JQuery global Placeholder replacement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, placeholder

Since I was not satisfied with the fact that some browsers do not support "placeholder"-Tag, I thought: "Why not develop a JS-Workaround when JS is mostly available".

So I build a form-input-search which makes all placeholder's behaviour in JS which has one advantage: onFocus will clear the field! 
The fact that placeholders do not clear the field onFocus was another reason to do this. So here is the Code, feel free to use and change it:

Comment: That's not a question. It's a blog post.

Comment: yet I questioned (!) myself howto solve this problem and yes I did answer my own question to help others, so?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('form').each(function(){
                var f = $(this);
                f.find('input[type=text]').each(function(){
                    var s = $(this);
                    var attr = s.attr('placeholder'); 
                    if (attr && $.trim(attr)!='') {
                        $.extend(this,{oldPlaceholder: s.attr('placeholder')})
                        s.removeAttr('placeholder');

                        if ($.trim(this.value)=='') {
                            this.value = this.oldPlaceholder;
                        }


                        s.focus(function(){
                            if ($.trim(s.val())==this.oldPlaceholder) {
                                s.val('');
                            }
                        });

                        s.blur(function(){
                            if ($.trim(s.val())=='') {
                                s.val(this.oldPlaceholder);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                f.submit(function(){
                    $(this).find('input[type=text]').each(function(){
                        if (this.oldPlaceholder && $.trim(this.value)==this.oldPlaceholder) {
                            this.value = '';
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```